# relationship of a relationship in scope - Yii

Tags: yii

how can i get data from one table to another table's table's relations? 
I have three tables: order, product, store. Within defaultscope, I have store_id in order model but that won't work because store_id is not in order table. But product_id is in order table which then can relate to store_id. The goal is obviously to filter out the store's orders.

Relations in Order:

```
'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
```

Relations in Product:

```
'orderProducts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'OrderProduct', 'product_id'),
'store' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Store', 'store_id'),
```

i'm quite new to everything, I'm trying to understand this. I saw a post where they put scopes in the relations? Also, not understanding getTableAlias. Explanations (the what) would be appreciative rather than what i found a lot of what's wrong with the scope.

Sorry for the super newbie question.

Comment: In you view, `$data->realtion1->relation2->column_name`?

Comment: But that would need to be used in every single view, doesn't seem efficient. Should be able to use scope and apply to through the pages, no?

Comment: I'm saying it'll work in view page. do you have more view page for same purpose?

Comment: Yes, there several pages. So applying through view is not too ideal.

Comment: No. It's idea to how to use 3rd level relation in yii. Add your code and tell me where do you want to add.

Comment: well i know how to use relation->relation->column... but what'youre saying is for every view I have to write that again and again? So when issues arise, I have to find all those same relationship that'scattered all over many pages?

Comment: Please make clear what your purpose is: filter a list of orders by store id of product that was in those orders?
Is this your model's relationship (orderProduct ~ orderItem in the given relationship) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155054/relationship-between-orders-customers-and-products?answertab=active#tab-top ?

Comment: yes but on store side. So instead of user it's stores. Problem is now I can see all orders regardless store ID (store sees all stores' info; user can't see store info. This was defined in role). So the filter is stores see its own store info, but there are times it needs to see other store info.  Hence, the scope but scope limits it to see other relations. Therefore, this question.